# Integral of $\cos^4(2t)\,dt$ with bounds from $0$ to $\pi$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^\pi\cos^4(2t)\,dt=?$$ I have attempted this problem two different ways and got two different answers that are nowhere near the correct answer. Could you please show me detailed steps on how to work this problem out. The final answer is $\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

Comment: Can you show us your intermediate steps?

Comment: I am still not very comfortable using the identities to evaluate integrals. Step 1: (1/2) Integral (1+ cos(4t))^2 dt     Step 2: (1/2) Integral (1+cos(4t))(1+cos(4t)) . I multiplied them after this and then split them up and then integrated them.

Answer (score 1):

$$I=\int_0^\pi\cos^4(2t)dt$$
Substitute: $u=2t\rightarrow du=2dt$,
$$I=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0\times 2}^{\pi\times 2}\cos^4(u)du=\dfrac{1}{2}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^4(u)du$$
Apply the reduction formula: $\int\cos^n(x)dx=\dfrac{\sin(x)\cos^{n-1}(x)}{n}+\dfrac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2}(x)dx$, with $n=4$ :
$$I=\left.\dfrac{1}{8}\sin(u)\cos^3(u)\right\vert_0^{2\pi}+\dfrac{3}{8}\int_0^{2\pi}\cos^2(u)du$$
Use the trigonometric identity: $\cos^2(x)=\dfrac{1}{2}\cos(2x)+\dfrac{1}{2}$,
$$I=0+\dfrac{3}{8}\int_0^{2\pi}\left(\dfrac{1}{2}\cos(2u)+\dfrac{1}{2}\right)du$$
Substitute: $v=2u\rightarrow dv=2du$,
$$I=\dfrac{3}{32}\int_{0\times 2}^{2\pi\times 2}\cos(v)dv+\dfrac{3}{16}\int_0^{2\pi}du$$
$$I=\left.\dfrac{3}{32}\sin(v)\right\vert_0^{4\pi}+\left.\dfrac{3}{16}u\right\vert_0^{2\pi}$$
$$I=0+\dfrac{3}{16}\left(2\pi-0\right)$$
$$I=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}$$
Conclude:
$$\int_0^{\pi}\cos^4(2t)dt=\dfrac{3\pi}{8}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Use the trigonometric identity bellow twice

$$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Use this reduction formula:
\begin{align}
\int \cos^n\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta & = \frac{\cos^{n-1}\left(\theta\right)\sin\left(\theta\right)}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n}\int\cos^{n-2}\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta.\tag{1}
\end{align}
See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_reduction_formulae) for an adequate derivation of the solution. There's also one for $\int\sin^{n}\left(\theta\right)\:d\theta$ and many others.

Comment: Isn't it $+\dfrac{n-1}{n}$?

Comment: @Demosthene I do believe you are right. Thanks for catching my error.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on Alex Silva's answer:

Since
$\cos^2(x) = \frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$,

$\begin{array}\\
\cos^4(x)
&= \frac{(1+\cos(2x))^2}{4}\\
&= \frac{1+2\cos(2x)+\frac{1+\cos(4x)}{2}}{4}\\
&= \frac{2+4\cos(2x)+1+\cos(4x)}{8}\\
&= \frac{3+4\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)}{8}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$\cos^4(2x)
=\frac{3+4\cos(4x)+\cos(8x)}{8}
$.

The integrals of the
$\cos(4x)$
and
$\cos(8x)$
terms are zero,
so the result is
$\frac{3\pi}{8}$.